# C# Serial Communication

Tags: c#, usb, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

How do I go about sending and receiving data from a USB comm port using C#?

The requirements for communication are:

- 115.2 kBaud
- 8-bit character size
- 1 stop bit
- No parity

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Well, you open the COM port, configure it and send and receive.

Comment: These settings only make sense if you *actually* connect to hardware through a physical serial port.  The chip is called a UART, Universal Asynchronous Receiver and Transmitter.  With a USB emulator it makes no difference whatsoever, the bus protocol doesn't require this kind of config.

Comment: @HansPassant, these settings are still very critical for a USB device that contains a UART.  There is no indication that he is using a USB device that does not contain a UART, and even then, the settings may still be enforced.  Some Symbol/Motorola USB scanners, which present themselves as serial ports, still require 9600/8/N/1 even though they are virtual ports.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A USB comm port appears to the system the same as an onboard port.  Use the [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class.

```
    using (var sp = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM11", 115200, System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, 8, System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One))
    {
        sp.Open();

        sp.WriteLine("Hello!");

        var readData = sp.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(readData);
    }
```

You can find the available ports by calling [SerialPort.GetPortNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames.aspx).  If that doesn't appeal to you, you can also access the port as a file, but that is much more complex and there are few reasons to do so.  See the documentation for [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more.

Comment: GetPortNames doesn't enumerate normal USB ports.

Comment: @user357320, GetPortNames will enumerate any device which presents itself as a COM port.  If the USB device does not present itself as a COM port, then it will not show up.  You'd need `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces` to get all USB devices, but unless you are writing a custom driver à la `winusb.sys`, that would not be very helpful.